# Make : delete target before making target

Tags: makefile, rm

this does not work :

```
CXXFLAGS =  -O2 -g -Wall -fmessage-length=0
OBJS =      src\Sfe.cpp
LIBS =
TARGET =      Sfe.exe

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    rm -f $(TARGET)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all: $(TARGET)
clean: rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

but this works :

```
OBJS =      src\Sfe.cpp
LIBS =
TARGET =      Sfe.exe

$(TARGET):  $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

all: 
    rm -f $(TARGET)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
clean: rm -f $(OBJS) $(TARGET)
```

I'd like to delete Sfe.exe before compiling a new one.
Why doesn't the first way function? 
It always answers with       make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

Answer (score 0):

make only rebuilds things that need to be rebuilt. It determines that from the timestamps of the prerequisites of the target. In your first example presumably the files in `$(OBJS)` are older than the binary in `$(TARGET)` already and so make doesn't believe it has anything to do.

In your second example the `all` target has no prerequisites and, as such, is always considered as needing to be built.

The better solution might be to either set your `$(TARGET)` target as `.PHONY` in your first example (see [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) of the GNU Make Manual for more on Phony Targets).

Alternatively, you could use a `force target` to do a similar task (but without some of the `.PHONY` side-effects). See [this section](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Force-Targets) of the GNU Make Manual for more information about that.

Comment: Thanks Etan.  So is the following true : ?
Under $(TARGET) : $(OBJ) you only have rules which deal with updating $(OBJ) and not $(TARGET)?

Comment: Strike that. I found it.  You have to change the insides of Sfe.cpp to cause the timestamp to indicate that Sfe.cpp is ! Older and therefore fresher ! than Sfe.exe.  When this is the case then !! all things under $(TARGET) : $(OBJS) are performed.

Comment: make rebuilds a target if any prerequisite is seen as newer, correct. And no, targets should always build the exact filename of the target. Using `$@` for that purpose is usually a good idea. And yes, you can always force a prerequisite to be newer or you can use of the methods in the answer to do a similar thing without changing modification times of arbitrary prerequisite files.